# Custom cluster on Google map for Xamarin iOS

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I implemented Google map clusters for my Xamarin.iOS.
I have a custom cluster with amount of markers into it.

Here is

[image: example]

I create a custom IconGenerator with inherited from `GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator`

```
class CustomIconGenerator : GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator
{
    public override UIImage IconForSize(nuint size)
    {
        UIImage textToImage = TextToImage(size);
        return textToImage;
    }

    private UIImage TextToImage(nuint size)
    {
        var text = size.ToString();
        var uiImage = UIImage.FromBundle("markClaster");
        nfloat fWidth = uiImage.Size.Width;
        nfloat fHeight = uiImage.Size.Height;

        CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();

        using (CGBitmapContext ctx = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, (nint) fWidth, (nint) fHeight, 8
                                                       , 4 * (nint) fWidth, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB()
                                                       , CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
        {
            ctx.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, (double) fWidth, (double) fHeight), uiImage.CGImage);

            ctx.SelectFont("Roboto-Bold", 12, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);

            //Measure the text's width - This involves drawing an invisible string to calculate the X position difference
            float start, end, textWidth;

            //Get the texts current position
            start = (float) ctx.TextPosition.X;
            //Set the drawing mode to invisible
            ctx.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
            //Draw the text at the current position
            ctx.ShowText(text);
            //Get the end position
            end = (float) ctx.TextPosition.X;
            //Subtract start from end to get the text's width
            textWidth = end - start;


            //Set the fill color to black. This is the text color.

            ctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.White.CGColor);

            //Set the drawing mode back to something that will actually draw Fill for example
            ctx.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);

            //Draw the text at given coords.
            ctx.ShowTextAtPoint(uiImage.Size.Width / 2 - textWidth / 2, uiImage.Size.Height / 2, text);

            return UIImage.FromImage(ctx.ToImage());
        }
    }
}
```

but result is unimpressive

[image]

if I change `FontName` to `Helvetica` result a bit better but not perfect.
Font is blurred and isn't centered.

[image]

I was thinking maybe solution to set, xib or UIView as cluster, is exists, but I didn't find any.